# TypeError: self.parent.parent.context.parseInt is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to assign height to a img using ngStyle and for that I'm calculating height with some Math operation as follows:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="tbNm?tbNm:'itm0'">
    <ion-list *ngFor="let vl of scrnshot;let ind=index">
      <img *ngSwitchCase="'itm'+ind" alt="Akhilesh" [ngStyle]="{'height':(parseInt(vl.names[0].hitWid.bdHt+(websitTyp(vl._id.origin)?100:0)))+'px','width':(vl.names[0].hitWid.bdWd+'px')}" [src]="vl.names[0].base64">
    </ion-list>
  </div>
```

But when I do run it it gives following error:

```
error_handler.js:51 TypeError: self.parent.parent.context.parseInt is not a function
    at DebugAppView._View_HomePage9.detectChangesInternal (HomePage.ngfactory.js:1444)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:377)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:290)
    at DebugAppView._View_HomePage8.detectChangesInternal (HomePage.ngfactory.js:1407)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
    at DebugAppView.detectChanges (view.js:377)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (view.js:290)
    at DebugAppView._View_HomePage0.detectChangesInternal (HomePage.ngfactory.js:270)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.detectChanges (view.js:272)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per documentation:

> Perhaps more surprising, template expressions cannot refer to anything
>   in the global namespace. They can’t refer to window or document. They
>   can’t call console.log or Math.max. They are restricted to referencing
>   members of the expression context.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html

You can work around it like:

```
class Component {
  myParseInt = parseInt;
}
```

html

```
[ngStyle]="{'height':(myParseInt (...
```